# ActiveMQ with JDBC Persistence results in OutOfMemory on the broker

Tags: java, postgresql, out-of-memory, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.16.0, broker is started with 512MB heap size (`-Xms=512m -Xmx=512`).
Configuration file `activemq.xml` looks like this:

```
<bean id="postgresql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=amq" />
    <property name="username" value="..." />
    <property name="password" value="..." />
</bean>

(...)

<systemUsage>
    <systemUsage>
        <memoryUsage>
            <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
        </memoryUsage>
        <storeUsage>
            <storeUsage limit="2 gb"/>
        </storeUsage>
        <tempUsage>
            <tempUsage limit="5 gb"/>
        </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>

(...)

<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="50 mb"  maxPageSize="100" maxBrowsePageSize="100" lazyDispatch="true"></policyEntry>
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

I'm using single producer which pushes 500 durable messages, with about 1MB per each message, into the single queue. After producer finishes producing messages everything seems to be ok, 500 records are available in `activemq_msgs` table and ActiveMQ web console shows about 9% memory percent used, which (if my calculations are correct) should be about right:

- `70% * 512MB = 358.4MB` - total available memory
- `70% * 50MB = 35MB` - total memory available for single queue
- `35MB / 358.4MB * 100 = ~9%` - memory used

Now, the problem occurs when I restart the broker. Shortly after AMQ is started I'm getting an exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2255)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:122)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:122)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.DefaultJDBCAdapter.doRecoverNextMessages(DefaultJDBCAdapter.java:1081)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(JDBCMessageStore.java:365)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyMessageStore.recoverNextMessages(ProxyMessageStore.java:110)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch.doFillBatch(QueueStorePrefetch.java:127)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.fillBatch(AbstractStoreCursor.java:476)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.reset(AbstractStoreCursor.java:179)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.StoreQueueCursor.reset(StoreQueueCursor.java:166)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doPageInForDispatch(Queue.java:2047)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.pageInMessages(Queue.java:2283)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doBrowse(Queue.java:1183)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.expireMessages(Queue.java:957)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.access$100(Queue.java:108)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue$2.run(Queue.java:152)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveTupleV3(PGStream.java:561)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2251)
        ... 23 more
```

I've checked PostgreSQL logs and I've noticed there is a `SELECT` query which pretty much retrieves whole table, so it looks like AMQ tries to load everything from the table, so possibly this is the cause of the OOM:

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT ID, MSG FROM ACTIVEMQ_MSGS WHERE CONTAINER=$1 AND ID < $2 AND ID > $3 AND XID IS NULL ORDER BY ID LIMIT 32767
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'queue://TEST', $2 = '501', $3 = '-1'
```

I tried to play a bit with Destination Policies properties like: `maxPageSize`, `lazyDispatch`, but it doesn't seem to have any impact on this issue.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I'll appreciate any ideas, thanks!